# Question to all Chemfig-enthusiasts: How to put '+' on same line

Tags: alignment, chemfig

Here's my little molecule so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}

\schemestart
\chemfig[atom sep=24pt]{C([2]-H)([4]-H)(-\charge{90=\|,-90=\|}{O}-H)([6,2]-C([4,1]-H)([0,1]-\charge{90=\|,-90=\|}{O}-H)([6,2]-C([6,1]-H)([4,1]-H)([0,1]-\charge{90=\|,-90=\|}{O}-[0,1]H)))}
\+ 
\chemfig[atom sep=24pt]{C([3,1]=O)([5,1]-H)([1,1]--[-1,1]-CH_3)} 
\+
\chemfig[atom sep=24pt]{C([3,1]=O)([5,1]-H)}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I want the next carboxyl group to be added to the next hydroxyl group

Thank you so much for dealing with this problem!

---

**Edit:** Evolved code:

```
\schemestart
\chemfig[atom sep=32pt]{C([2]-H)([4]-H)(-\charge{90=\|,-90=\|}{O}-@{h1}H)([6,2]-C([4,1]-H)([0,1]-\charge{90=\|,-90=\|}{O}-@{h2}H)([6,2]-C([6,1]-@{c3}H)([4,1]-H)([0,1]-\charge{90=\|,-90=\|}{O}-[0,1]@{h3}H)))}
\arrow(@{c3}--)[-90,1]
\chemfig[atom sep=32pt]{C([2]-@{hh1}H)([4]-H)(-\charge{90=\|,-90=\|}{O}-H)([6,2]-C([4,1]-H)([0,1]-\charge{90=\|,-90=\|}{O}-H)([6,2]-C([6,1]-@{c3}H)([4,1]-H)([0,1]-\charge{90=\|,-90=\|}{O}-[0,1]H)))}
\arrow(@{h1}--){0}[0,0.063]\+ 
\chemfig[atom sep=24pt]{C([3,1]=O)([5,1]-H)([1,0.5]--[-1,0.5]-CH_3)} 
\arrow(@{h3}--){0}[0,0.063]\+
\chemfig[atom sep=24pt]{C([3,1]=O)([5,1]-H)([1,0.5]--[-1,0.5]--[-1,0.5]--[-1,0.5]--[-1,0.5]--[-1,0.5]--[-1,0.5]--[-1,0.5]-CH_3)} 
\arrow(@{h2}--){0}[0,0.063]\+
\chemfig[atom sep=24pt]{C([3,1]=O)([5,1]-H)([1,0.5]--[-1,0.5]--[-1,0.5]--[-1,0.5]--[-1,0.5]=-[-1,0.5]--[-1,0.5]--[-1,0.5]--[-1,0.5]-CH_3)} 
\schemestop
```

Here I absolutely want the arrow pointing from the Hydrogen atom directly to the other Hydrogen atom

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the picture. You want to vertically center also the left molecule so the + is midway?

Comment: As explained in the documentation, each molecule is placed so that the first atom specified sits on the current baseline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}
    
    \schemestart
    \chemfig[atom sep=24pt]{C([2]-H)([4]-H)(-\charge{90=\|,-90=\|}{O}-H)([6,2]-C([4,1]-H)([0,1]-\charge{90=\|,-90=\|}{O}-@{a}H)([6,2]-C([6,1]-H)([4,1]-H)([0,1]-\charge{90=\|,-90=\|}{O}-[0,1]H)))}
    \+ 
    \chemfig[atom sep=24pt]{C([3,1]=O)([5,1]-H)([1,1]--[-1,1]-CH_3)} 
    \arrow(@{a}--){0}[0,.1]\+
    \chemfig[atom sep=24pt]{C([3,1]=O)([5,1]-H)}
    \schemestop
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh Yes, that's what I have been trying to achieve for ages!

Comment: If I may bother you again a new problem came along. May you take a glance at it once more?

Comment: Yes, but do it with a new question

Comment: How it comes: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/647499/part-2-chemfig-aligning-arrows